# How should unit tests for beans that perform CRUD operations be designed?

Tags: java, unit-testing, jakarta-ee, mocking

I am developing a Java EE 7 based application which uses a combination of EJB, CDI and JPA to perform create, read, update and delete operations against a SQL database. I would like to develop a series of unit tests for the service layer of my application but I am struggling to see how I can create any meaningful unit test cases which add value and aren't just unit tests for the sake of code coverage. Most of the examples I've found are in fact integration tests which use an in-memory database.

The service layer of the application is designed using the Entity, Control, and Boundary pattern.

The Entity is a JPA annotated bean containing various getters, setters and named queries, along with the standard toString, equals and hashCode methods.

The Control is a CDI managed bean annotated with @Dependent and contains create, update, delete void methods which invoke the JPA entity manager persist, merge and remove methods. The control also contains a few read methods which use either a JPA named query or the JPA criteria API to return a List object from the database. The create, update and delete methods perform some basic checks such as checking whether the record already exists, but again this is done via the relevant JPA EntityManager methods.

The boundary is an EJB managed bean annotated with @Stateless and contains methods that would be recognisable to an end user such as createWidget, deleteWidget, updateWidget, activateWidget, discontinueWidget, findAllWidgets and findASpecificWidget. For more complex entities the boundary will apply business logic, but a number of entities are very simple and don't contain any business logic. The createWidget, deleteWidget, updateWidget, activateWidget, discontinueWidget methods are declared as void and make use of exceptions to handle failures such a database constraint violation which is then passed up to the web layer of the application to present a user friendly message back to the user.

I know that when writing unit tests, I should test the method in isolation using a mocking framework to emulate things such as EntityManager and that when a method is declared as void the test case should check whether the state of has been changed correctly. The issue is I'm struggling to see how most of the unit tests would be doing anything more than checking the mocking framework is working correctly rather than my application code.

My question is how should I design meaningful unit tests to validate the correct operation of the boundary and control components, given that the control component is just calling various JPA EntityManager methods and the boundary component is in several cases applying no business logic? Alternatively in this instance is there no benefit and instead I should concentrate on writing integration tests.

**Update**

The following is an example of a service component which is used to maintain a list of widgets:

```
public class WidgetService {

    @PersistenceContext
    public EntityManager em;

    public void createWidget(Widget widget) {

        if (checkIfWidgetDiscontinued(widget.getWidgetCode())) {
            throw new ItemDiscontinuedException(String.format(
                    "Widget %s already exists and has been discontinued.",
                    widget.getWidgetCode()));
        }

        if (checkIfWidgetExists(widget.getWidgetCode())) {
            throw new ItemExistsException(String.format("Widget %s already exists",
                    widget.getWidgetCode()));
        }

        em.persist(widget);
        em.flush();
    }

    public void updateWidget(Widget widget) {
        em.merge(widget);
        em.flush();
    }

    public void deleteWidget(Widget widget) {
        try {
            Object ref = em.getReference(Widget.class, widget.getWidgetCode());
            em.remove(ref);
            em.flush();
        } catch (PersistenceException ex) {
            Throwable rootCause = ExceptionUtils.getRootCause(ex);
            if (rootCause instanceof SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException) {
                throw new DatabaseConstraintViolationException(rootCause);
            } else {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }

    public List<Widget> findWithNamedQuery(String namedQueryName,
            Map<String, Object> parameters, int resultLimit) {
        Set<Map.Entry<String, Object>> rawParameters = parameters.entrySet();
        Query query = this.em.createNamedQuery(namedQueryName);
        if (resultLimit > 0) {
            query.setMaxResults(resultLimit);
        }
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : rawParameters) {
            query.setParameter(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
        return query.getResultList();
    }

    public List<Widget> findWithComplexQuery(int first, int pageSize, String sortField,
            SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters) {

        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Widget> q = cb.createQuery(Widget.class);
        Root<Widget> referenceWidget = q.from(Widget.class);
        q.select(referenceWidget);

        //Code to apply sorting and build filterCondition removed for brevity

        q.where(filterCondition);

        TypedQuery<Widget> tq = em.createQuery(q);
        if (pageSize >= 0) {
            tq.setMaxResults(pageSize);
        }
        if (first >= 0) {
            tq.setFirstResult(first);
        }

        return tq.getResultList();
    }

    public long countWithComplexQuery(Map<String, Object> filters) {

        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Long> q = cb.createQuery(Long.class);
        Root<Widget> referenceWidget = q.from(Widget.class);
        q.select(cb.count(referenceWidget));

        //Code to build filterCondition removed for brevity

        q.where(filterCondition);

        TypedQuery<Long> tq = em.createQuery(q);

        return tq.getSingleResult();
    }


    private boolean checkIfWidgetExists(String widgetCode) {
        int count;
        Query query = em.createNamedQuery(Widget.COUNT_BY_WIDGET_CODE);
        query.setParameter("widgetCode", widgetCode);
        count = ((Number) query.getSingleResult()).intValue();

        if (count == 1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private boolean checkIfWidgetDiscontinued(String widgetCode) {
        int count;
        Query query = em
                .createNamedQuery(Widget.COUNT_BY_WIDGET_CODE_AND_DISCONTINUED);
        query.setParameter("widgetCode", widgetCode);
        query.setParameter("discontinued", true);
        count = ((Number) query.getSingleResult()).intValue();

        if (count == 1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
 }
```

The following is an example of a boundary component which is used to maintain a list of widgets:

```
@Stateless
public class WidgetBoundary {

    @Inject
    private WidgetService widgetService;

    public void createWidget(Widget widget) {
        widgetService.createWidget(widget);
    }

    public void updateWidget(Widget widget) {
        widgetService.updateWidget(widget);
    }

    public void deleteWidget(Widget widget) {
        widgetService.deleteWidget(widget);
    }

    public void activateWidget(String widgetCode) {
        Widget widget;

        widget = widgetService.findWithNamedQuery(Widget.FIND_BY_WIDGET_CODE,
                QueryParameter.with("widgetCode", widgetCode).parameters(), 0).get(0);

        widget.setDiscontinued(false);
        widgetService.updateWidget(widget);
    }

    public void discontinueWidget(Widget widget) {
        widget.setDiscontinued(true);
        widgetService.updateWidget(widget);
    }

    public List<Widget> findWithComplexQuery(int first, int pageSize, String sortField,
            SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters) {
        return widgetService.findWithComplexQuery(first, pageSize, sortField, sortOrder,
                filters);
    }

    public Long countWithComplexQuery(Map<String, Object> filters) {
        return widgetService.countWithComplexQuery(filters);
    }

    public List<Widget> findAvailableWidgets() {
        return widgetService.findWithNamedQuery(Widget.FIND_BY_DISCONTINUED, QueryParameter.with("discontinued", false).parameters(), 0);
    }

}
```

Comment: TL;DR. Don't post a description of your code. Post the code.

Comment: I think you hit the nail on the head when you point out that testing simple CRUD beans is not doing a whole lot. Still, it doesn't hurt to have them. Your more important tests will be around your facade's, which will be combining business logic and (possibly) crud operations. Using good facade's (see design patterns) makes for good code and meaningful tests. My 2 cents worth.

Comment: @JBNizet The question didn't relate directly to the code I've already got but rather the concept of writing unit tests for CRUD beans. As you said in your comment the question is already very long and I didn't want to make it any longer than necessary by adding code and instead hoped that a description would suffice. Nevertheless I've updated the question to include two example classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is hard to test because the responsibilities aren't correctly separated.

The WidgetBoundary almost doesn't do anything, and delegates everything to the WidgetService.

The WidgetService mixes business logic (like checking if a widget is discontinued before creating it) with persistence logic (like saving or querying widgets).

That makes the WidgetBoundary completely dumb, and not really worth to test, whereas the WidgetService is too complex to be tested easily.

The business logic should be moved to the boundary (which I would call a service). The service (which should be called a DAO) should only contain persistence logic.

That way, you can test that the queries executed by the DAO work correctly (by populating your database with test data, calling the query method, and see if it returns the correct data).

And you can also test the business logic easily and quickly, by mocking the DAO. That way, you don't need any database to test the business logic. For example, a test of the `createWidget()` method could look like this:

```
@Test(expected = ItemDiscontinuedException)
public void createWidgetShouldRejectDiscontinuedWidget() {
    WidgetDao mockDao = mock(WidgetDao.class);
    WidgetService service = new WidgetService(mockDao);
    when(mockDao.countDiscontinued("someCode").thenReturn(1);

    Widget widget = new Widget("someCode");
    service.createWidget(widget);                
}
```

Comment: Thanks and now I see why should have included the code :) Do you see any benefit in unit testing the DAO with a mocking framework or is this best left to integration testing with a real database?

Comment: No, I don't see any value in using mocks for DAO tests.